# Social Plugins on my website, but with no Facebook app

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, facebook-social-plugins

I want to use Facebook social plugins (mainly the like one), but I don't want Facebook to consider my website as a real application.

After googling a lot, I noticed that even if we don't plan to have a Facebook app, we must register an app, just to get an app_id and supply it for the OG metatags on our websites. So I did this, but I think Facebook sees this as an actual app, but this is not what I want.

Here's an example, I implemented Facebook like on this website (see the like button near the footer):

```
http://www.padariaitalianinha.com.br
```

It's working very well, you can click Like, leave a comment and so on. However, after "liking" it, if I go to my recent activity in Facebook, I see something like this:

> USER likes PAGE_TITLE in **APP_NAME**

Where USER is my name, PAGE_TITLE is the page title supplied in og:title, and APP_NAME, is the app name I used when registering the app at Facebook, just to obtain the app_id!

This is the part annoying me, because it assumes the application really exists, and if I click on it (APP_NAME), an error occurs, probably because the app doesn't exist!

So, I'm looking for a way to make the Like appear just as this:

> USER likes PAGE_TITLE

It's just as before, but with no app name. Is that possible?

Thanks a lot in advance!